# Rails run after create on parent model after saving parent model AND nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating a new resource in my Rails app, the JSON sent to my endpoint looks like this:

```
{
  "resource1": {
    "resource2_attributes": [{
      "name": "Test 1",
      "resource3_attributes": [{
        "field1": "test"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

The nested attributes are working correctly, and the associations on the parent model are being set.

However, when `resource1` at the top level is saved, the `after_create` callback on the model is triggered (prior to saving the associations).  The `after_create` callback on `Resource1` uses the child associations for its logic.

How can I make my Rails app save the parent model along with the child associations, *and then* run the callback?

Comment: Turns out this is a silly question that isn't possible in Rails as o Feb 19, 2016.  Check my answer to see the alternative options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Rails isn't capable of doing what I'm trying to do at the time of this post.

I was suggested to add an `after_add` association callback, which worked, except the record passed through to the method didn't have an `id` set yet because it hasn't committed it to the database.  The `after_add` method needed access to the `id`, because it was creating associated records but couldn't do so without the `id`.

Next option:

Rather using an `after_add` callback on the association, and since it wouldn't work adding an ActiveRecord callback on the parent model because order of execution is like so: Save Parent -> Run Parent Callback -> Save Children, when the "Run Parent Callback" part needed the children data, but couldn't get at it because it hadn't been created due to order of operations.

So, the route I ended up taking is putting the callback on the child model and referencing the parent association for the data I need.

Not the most preferred way to do it, because I can't have the logic in the parent model which is where, in my opinion, it should belong, but at least everything runs smoothly and the data makes sense.